# Cropped image using the package title

Tags: frontespizio

I used the `frontespizio` package to create the cover of my thesis, but when I insert the image (symbol of the university) it is cut. I don't know why.
The image is in the right size and not cut, but when it is inserted with the package is slightly cut off at the edges.
Change the size in which it is to be inserted doesn't solve the problem.

Frontespizio file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{frontespizio.tex}
\begin{frontespizio}
\Margini{3cm}{2cm}{3cm}{2cm} %sx, basso, dx, alto
\Universita{bla bla}
\Logo[4cm]{sigillo}
\Facolta{bla bla}
\Corso[bla bla]{bla bla}
\Annoaccademico{2014--2015}
\Titoletto{bla bla}
\Titolo{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\Candidato[bla bla]{bla bla}
\Relatore{bla bla}
\end{frontespizio}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
        \input{frontespizio}

    %...

\end{document}
```

Image:
[image]

Image once inserted in the thesis:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Isn't there the `frontespizio` package missing in the document? For this particular problem, all other chapters and the bibliography aren't necessary, in my point of view, so that part code can be removed for the phase of error solving

Comment: Using your code and the image above, I get a non-cropped image

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Mmm strange...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Which may be the reason why I see it cut?

Comment: Here's the image I saved as a screenshot from the output: http://i.imgur.com/6BTNHXB.jpg

Comment: Do you mean you see it cut with different code? Does the exact code posted produce the cropped image?

Comment: @cfr That code produces the cutted image.

Comment: @cfr: From that code above with the posted huge image there's no cropping

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But to me it is still not working. Sorry I'm novice with LaTeX, I have no idea where I'm wrong

Comment: With that code, I get errors. If I add the frontespizio package, I get a blank page. Of course, I had to rename the files a bit because I don't have those directories.

Comment: @cfr: You have to remove a lot of stuff and you have to recompile the foo-frn.tex file which is generated during the run

Comment: Does the image appear uncropped if you zoom in? It seems to be an artefact of the PDF viewer. I see the cropping but the image is all there really - if I zoom in, this is clear. I've edited the example slightly to make it easier for people who are not identical with you and no not have identical directory hierarchies in their testing directories.

Comment: Sorry, but I see no issue.

Comment: @cfr if I zoom the pdf then I see the image correctly. I might have problems with the print? The image will be cut or not?

Comment: @lonely Very unlikely. It will almost certainly print fine. At least, my stuff usually does (at least, it doesn't have this problem ;) ) when I see such artefacts. It is very, very common with many PDF viewers.